# Any subset of a metric space is an infinite union of some individual elements of the space?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $E$ be a metric space such that the set $\{x\}$ is open $ \forall x \in E$. Does the following proposition make sense?

All subsets of $E$ are open.
Proof: $\forall S \subset E$, there are points $x_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $S = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i$. Since the union of open sets is open, any $S$ is open in $E$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is true, but your argument is false: what if $S$ is uncountable?

The key is that a union of *arbitrarily many* open sets is still open - can you see a way of writing $S$ as a union of open sets? HINT: each $\{x\}\subseteq S$ is open . . .

Comment: Ah I see. I can write $S$ as the union of an infinite number of open balls centered at the points $x \in S$. So, $S = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_{\epsilon_i}(x_i), \forall x_i \in S$ and $ \epsilon_i$ chosen accordingly. Hence $S$ is open.

Comment: @sid Yes but your notation is confused and, well, wrong. There's no index $'$ ranging from $1$ to $\infty$ involved. That means a union over a countable collection. If $S$ is uncountable, you cannot enumerate the $x$s in $S$. It's a union over the $x\in S$. Finally, you should use $\bigcup$ (\bigcup) in this situation.